# Refresh HTML Report View During A Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using **HTML Publisher Plugin** to display test results report as HTML. the tests run-time is about 4 hours and the HTML report is been updated with the tests results during running.

I have the first part of test results after an hour and I want to display it immediately.
After I get the other parts of the report I want to refresh the report view during running.

When I run both tasks in parallel I get a new tab to a new report for each time I run the publisher command when I wanted just to update the existing report view.

Any idea how to solve it?

```
def runRegressionTestsInRemoteServer(globals, testMode, pcapsToRun) {
    echo '*** Run-Regression-Tests ***'
    def tasks = [:]

    tasks["Regression-Test"] = {
        stage ('Run-Regression-Test'){
                tests_function()
        }
    }
    tasks["HTML-Publisher"] = {
        stage ('HTML-Report'){
                while (! finishRegressionTests){
                    DownloadHTMLReport()
                    DisplayHTMLReport()
            }
        }
    }

    parallel tasks
}
```

the result I get is :

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet of the HTML Publisher Plugin? Did you try to set 'alwaysLinkToLastBuild' to true for the plugin?

Comment: publishHTML([
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: '',
            reportFiles: 'report.html',
            reportName: 'HTML Report',
            reportTitles: ''])

Comment: Try to set the value for 'alwaysLinkToLastBuild' to true, maybe it will help but I can't promise anything.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and update.

Comment: "alwaysLinkToLastBuild" option is not according to results per pipeline? I use "keepAll: true" in order to get results per build.

Comment: didn't work :(, any other idea?

Comment: I am sorry :/ I don't have another idea, sorry